# If $5x+3$ divides evenly into $10x^3 + x^2 + 32x + k$, find the value of $k$.

Tags: polynomials

If $5x+3$ divides evenly into $10x^3 + x^2 + 32x + k$, find the value of $k$.

This is a polynomial division question and I'm not sure how to do it.

I keep getting the wrong answer. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. What have you tried? What are the wrong answers you got?

Comment: Please show us your workings; if you arrive at a wrong answer, that's okay.  Doing so will help us spot any mistakes.  Don't come here asking to have someone do your work for you.  Show your work, and many will be able to best help you learn from any mistakes, and correct them.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to show the long division here, but the goal is, basically, to focus step by step on each of the terms of $10x^3 + x^2 + 32x + k$ until we end up with something of a lower degree than the divisor. From there, you want to set that 'remainder' -- it isn't really a remainder here -- equal to $0$ and solve for $k$. I just worked this out and the math seems reasonably straightforward.

Comment: I got 35-k/5+3 as my final answer. My quotient was 2x^2 + x^2 + 7 (35-k)/5x+3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: We get

$$\frac{10x^3+x^2+32x+k}{5x+3}=2x^2-x+7+\frac{k-21}{5x+3}$$

Comment: Fantastic. I get the hang of it now. It took a while but I followed this example and I know where I went wrong. Just did another question and got it right! Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Note that if $5x+3 \mid 10x^3 + x^2 + 32x + k$, then we get that $x = -\frac{3}{5}$ is a root of the second polynomial, as it's already a root of the first one. Thus you need to find the value $k$ s.t.

$$0 = 10 \left(-\frac{3}{5}\right)^2 + \left(-\frac{3}{5}\right)^2 + 32\left(-\frac{3}{5}\right) + k$$

Now just find the actual value of $k$.